# Since what version of Laravel, variables passed with compact to route need to be called the same as parameters?

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-upgrade

I have upgrade Laravel from **5.8** to **8.0**.
I've noticed the section about **URL Generation** in [Upgrade Guide for Laravel 6](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade), but I also noticed different behavior, which is not described in any upgrade guide (or maybe I missed something).

In older version I was able to put any variable to a route using **compact()** and it was matched with possible route params, for example if route was
"xyz/{user}/{article}" and I used it like "route('xyz', compact('superAdminUser', 'theBestArticle'))" - this was correctly passed into route automaticaly.

**Now variables must be called the same as params defined in web.php.** Let's take a basic example with blog posts.

```
Route::get('/article/{article}', 'ArticlesController@show')->name('articles.show');

// Correct in Laravel 5.8 and not in Laravel 8
route('articles.show', compact('post'))

// Correct in Laravel 8
route('articles.show', compact('article'))
```

**My question is:** Since what version of Laravel this behavior has changed?

Comment: What does it matter? Just do it the documented way, and it will work in all versions.

Comment: @miken32 I know, but I'd like to know what happens and why :) For example if someone will have such problem with it, what will I answer him? "I don't know why, but change your code this way"? I don't think you would vote for this as the best answer.